# What is the meaning of Ecosystem in software?

Tags: node.js

I need to know the meaning of Ecosystem in software with examples. Specially, I can find this term widely used in node.js related documentations.

Comment: It means simply the community and resources available around a platform - people, forums, companies, products, code repositories, conferences, documentation.... (This isn't a good question for Stack Overflow, though.)

Comment: have you tried googling "ecosystem software"?  gee wiz man

Comment: @Pekka웃 Thank you very much for your useful answer. But can I know please what is the problem to post this question in stachoverflow? Is it software related question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic explains these matters quite clearly. This site isn't about *software*, it is about *programming*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term "Ecosystem" is used to describe the community around a software component, library, or tool. This includes the both complimentary tools to that component, active community members willing to help on online channels and support by prominent commercial/official organizations.